# Sending simple text data live from Android client to server

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server, low-latency

I've seen other posts on streaming live audio and video from an android application to a desktop server, but not yet for simple textual data. Basically, I'm trying to send key values from the android keyboard directly to a desktop server (which is implemented in java) as I type on the client. This would be a simple remote-keyboard sort of application that displays a keyboard on the android device and sends the live key taps to a server, which accesses the PC keyboard via the Robot class. I understand how to send text from the device to a server, but I am stuck on how to make the transfer of the text data to the server instantaneous, as the user types on the device.

I've tried to adapt from the examples for live video/audio streaming, but I couldn't figure out how they worked as I am still very new to client/server programming and programming in general.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure whether this will help you, but you can look into "CouchDB" for keeping data synced on client and server side instantaneously.

Comment: I think you should use some socket client configured for both desktop and mobile app. Node.js is a good example.

Comment: I am trying to write the server in pure java, so I'm looking for an efficient low-latency real time streaming of data from the client to the server. I realize I could do this by pushing the data every 100 or so milliseconds, but I was wondering if there were any libraries for real-time data push in java.